# Split names on a string with Regex with case sensitive characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

I want to split names into array with these kind of string.

```
Bol BolLouis King
Brandon ClarkeRui Hachimura
Michael Jeffery JordanDennis Rodman
```

to

```
['Bol Bol', 'Louis King']
['Brandon Clarke', 'Rui Hachimura']
['Michael Jeffery Jordan', 'Dennis Rodman']
```

I have already retied creating my own regex using `^[A-Z]\w+\s[A-Z][a-z]+` but this only matches the first name and i can't capture the 2nd or 3rd name. I'm also having some issues when the name has 3 words on it like `Michael Jeffery Jordan`

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/orNtbj/1) what you want?

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: @Toto Yes this is exactly what i want thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making use of a positive lookahead to be able to generalize your pattern. That allows you to match an expression that is immediately followed by some other expression. Use a (?=someRegexp) at the end of your pattern to make the end be the case where a lowercase character is immediately followed by an uppercase one. You can then generalize to any number of words.

I would also suggest splitting it into two cases then, as the last name in your expression wouldn’t be followed by a capital letter but rather by a end of string character. You can do that with an or: (someRegexp|someOtherRegexp)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say where you want this so here is a sed version, which works for your sample input:

`sed -e "s/\(.*[a-z]\)\([A-Z].*\)/['\1', '\2']/g"`

Answer (score 0):

As not all browsers support lookbehind, here is a solution without:

```js
var test = [
    'Bol BolLouis King',
    'Brandon ClarkeRui Hachimura',
    'Michael Jeffery JordanDennis Rodman',

];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  // return a + ' :' + a.match(/\b[a-z]{1,2}\K\s/);
  return a.match(/^(.+?[a-z])([A-Z].+)/);
}));
```